# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-dom, react-map-gl

### PLEASE HELP ME !

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOQrC.png * ERROR MESSAGE

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5iir.png * SOURCE CODE

Comment: post code instead of screenshots.

Comment: can you show us the code where you are consuming the Haber component like you are passing the news attribute or not.

Answer (score 0):

That means you do not pass the data correctly to props

Comment: Please try to be more specific next time or add this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the news is an array with some elements because if it's null or undefined then the map function won't work. Also if you fetch the news array from an api then until you get the data from the api your news array will stay undefined and your map function won't work.